# не видны ветки удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, gitlab

у меня есть уже развернутый локальный проект и в гитлабе тоже присутствует уже репозиторий, как подключиться к репозиторию так, чтобы были видны все ветки удаленной репы.
пробовал инициализировать гит

git init и затем git remote add origin 'ссылка на репозиторий'

Но при данном подключении не видна ни одна ветка удаленного репозитория (именно в phpStorm)

Answer (score 0):

Удаленные ветки появятся только после команды git pull или git fetch.
Образно говоря git pull команда двухэтапная. Сначала происходит git fetch и скачиваются удаленные ветки с репозитория, а потом происходит merge слияние удаленной ветки с локальной.

Comment: Сделал git pull, только в терминале вижу, как добавились нужные ветки, но почему-то в графическом оторбражении phpStorm их также не видать

Comment: я графическим не пользуюсь - не подскажу. Попробуйте git branch - посмотреть доступные ветки, переключится с помощью git checkout в интересующую ветку - и проверьте ваше графическое отображение - обновилось ли?